# Is there a guideline for downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm just curious if there exists an actual guideline for when to use downvotes.  Are they used solely for questions worded poorly or with little/no research?  Are they used when you don't understand the question?

I mean, I know people will use them however they want, but I'm just curious if some sort of "best use policy" was ever covered?

Comment: Similar question on Meta SO: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

Comment: [Why, yes, there is!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaeH4.jpg)

Comment: There's also a tooltip on each vote button.